# Confused by parameters example given in college lecture

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

Sorry to post such a specific question, but I'm confused by an example question given in college. The question is:

```
class BoundingBox {
private:
    float m_width;
    float m_height;
public:
    BoundingBox(float width = 0, float height = 0) :
        m_width(width), m_height(height) {}
};


class Enemy {
private:
    EnemyType m_type;
    BoundingBox m_box;

    Enemy(BoundingBox const & box, EnemyType type = EnemyType::Boss) :
        m_type(type);
        m_box(box);
        {}
};
```

Q: Is the following construction of `Enemy` legal? Explain.

```
Enemy enemy1(10);
```

The answer supplied says that it is, because the 10 is passed in as the `width` parameter and the default is used for the `height`, and also the default is used for the `EnemyType`. But from my understanding, the line:

```
BoundingBox const & box
```

is expecting a `box` object to be passed to it, not a parameter for it's constructor.

Has my lecturer made a mistake, or am I missing something? If I have misunderstood, could you provide me with a link that explains what is happening 'under the hood' so to speak. I didn't know this was a valid way to construct an object. I would ask my lecturer but he's been out sick for a week, and I can't find anything online about parameter based construction.

Comment: The constructor `BoundingBox(float,float)` is not marked explicit, so the compiler is free to implicitly convert `10` to `float` and then to `BoundingBox`. By the same token you are allowed to write `BoundingBox box = 10;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is fine and will compile (barring the syntax and access to the constructor).

To create the type `Enemy`, a `BoundingBox` is required; in particular the `Enemy` constructor accepts the argument as a `const&` thus allowing temporary values to be used.

To create the `BoundingBox`, no argument, one `float` or two `float`s can be used. The variation is because default arguments are supplied in the `BoundingBox` constructor. The constructor is not marked `explicit` (and this is the key bit that makes it work), the compiler is thus allowed to [implicitly create](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) the `BoundingBox` temporary by itself - which it duly does and then creates the `Enemy` object.

Adding an `explicit` will result in a compilation failure; it would be constructive for you to do this, and observe the error messages you receive. I suspect this could the subject of future lectures as well.

In general and often, advice is given to mark constructors that could take a single argument (taking into account defaults) as `explicit` thus preventing unknown (or unseen) conversions. If the implicit conversion is required, then don't add the `explicit`.

---

Code with the syntax issues cleared up;

```
class BoundingBox {
private:
    float m_width;
    float m_height;
public:
    /*explicit*/ BoundingBox(float width = 0, float height = 0) :
    // ^^^^^^^ experiment with and without this being present
        m_width(width), m_height(height) {}
};

class Enemy {
private:
    EnemyType m_type;
    BoundingBox m_box;
public:
// ^^^ added to allow access to the constructor
    Enemy(BoundingBox const & box, EnemyType type = EnemyType::Boss) :
        m_type(type),
        //          ^ syntax here
        m_box(box)
        //        ^ syntax here
        {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Is there a name for this type of 'waterfall' construction so I can research the topic a little deeper?

Comment: There's no "waterfall construction" there's just an implicit conversion from "10" to "BoundingBox" going on. The details of all the rules can be read in the standard or more comfortably on the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)